# Pandas.dataframe.query() - fetch not null rows (Pandas equivalent to SQL: "IS NOT NULL")

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am fetching the rows with some values from a pandas dataframe with the following code. I need to convert this code to `pandas.query()`.

```py
results = rs_gp[rs_gp['Col1'].notnull()]
```

When I convert to:

```py
results = rs_gp.query('Col1!=None')
```

It gives me the error

```
None is not defined
```

Comment: what is the dtype of `Col1`?

Comment: Hi Max, datatype is string

Answer (score 36, accepted):

We can use the fact that `NaN != NaN`:

```
In [1]: np.nan == np.nan
Out[1]: False
```

So comparing column to itself will return us only non-NaN values:

```
rs_gp.query('Col1 == Col1')
```

Demo:

```
In [42]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['aaa', np.nan, 'bbb', None, '', 'ccc']})

In [43]: df
Out[43]:
   Col1
0   aaa
1   NaN
2   bbb
3  None
4
5   ccc

In [44]: df.query('Col1 == Col1')
Out[44]:
  Col1
0  aaa
2  bbb
4
5  ccc
```

Answer (score 11):

I don't know, if my solution was added to pandas after the first answer on this question, but notnull() and isnull() are now valid options for queries in pandas.

```
df.query('Col1.isnull()', engine='python')
```

This will return all rows where the value in the cell of the row is null.

```
df.query('Col1.notnull()', engine='python')
```

Vice versa, this query will return every row, where the value is **not** NaN.

In Addition: stating the engine and setting it to python will let you use pandas functions in a query.

Comment: Worked great--didn't need to supply `engine=`